# Filenames without absolute path from Directory.GetFiles

Tags: asp.net, directory

```
string[] arrVideos = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~\\video\\"));

ddlVideos.DataSource = arrVideos;
ddlVideos.DataBind();
```

output Dropdownlist ddlVideos:

```
C:\video\movie.mp4
```

but I want this as output:

```
movie.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get rid of the full path:

```
var arrVideos = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~\\video\\"));

var withExtension = arrVideos.Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
var withoutExtension = arrVideos.Select(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p));
```

**Sidenote:** You can omit the `ToArray` to avoid re-copying the whole list into a new array. The `Select` extension method returns an `IEnumerable<String>` which I guess is fine for `ddlVideos`.

Comment: what should I do to become as output movie?

Comment: @Will_G I edited my answer. There is another static method of the `Path` class to get it. I encourage you to have a look into the MSDN API documentation of `Path`. It's actually a helpful resource, in general too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/beth2052.aspx